# IntegrityError : null value in column of relation " violates not-null constraint

Tags: django

'm building a small webstore , in the product page i put the order form using FormMixin and TemplateView, when i submit the order i get a " null value in column "customer_id" of relation "products_order" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (21, null)." error :

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    nominal_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='prix normal',)
    reduced_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="img/products/", default="img/products/user_default.png")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Customer(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1500, null=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

class Order (models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='OrderProduct')
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py** :

```
class ProductDetailView(FormMixin, TemplateView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product.html'
    form_class = OrderForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('index')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if context['form'].is_valid():
            product = get_object_or_404(Product, name=self.kwargs['product_name'])
            customer = form.save()
            instance = Order.objects.create(customer=customer)
            instance.product.set(product)

        return super(TemplateView, self)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['product'] = Product.objects.get(name=self.kwargs['product_name'])
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path ('<str:product_name>/', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product'),
    path('categories/', views.CategoryListView.as_view(), name='categories'),
    path('add_category', views.AddCategoryView.as_view(), name='add_category'),
    path('add_product/', views.AddProductView.as_view(), name='add_product'),
    path('categories/<str:category_name>/', views.CategoryProductsView.as_view(), name='category_products'),
 ]
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Django\Django projects\Store\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Django projects\Store\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 119, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Django projects\Store\venv\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: You're trying to create ``instance= Order.objects.create()`` but you didn't provided ``customer`` relation

Comment: @AnkitTiwari i edited the views in the question, and now i get the error : 'Product' object is not iterable

Comment: Hello @WalidOuzzane can you provide full traceback

Comment: Hello @AnkitTiwari ,
i put the traceback in the question, Thanks

Comment: Can you provide full error

Comment: instance.product = product not instance.product.set(product)

Comment: Actually ``get_object_or_404`` returns single object you can't iterate it and you have add that object like this ``instance.product.add(product)``

Comment: @AnkitTiwari 
TypeError at /Produit Maison 2/
'Product' object is not iterable

Comment: Did your problem solved?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari
i changed the `get_object_or_404 ` to Product.objects.filter and now i got another error :
'super' object has no attribute 'get'
:(

Comment: I din't said to change ``get_object_or_404`` with filter if you want to add ``get_object_or_404`` you can but use ``add()`` method ``instance.product.add(product)``

Comment: It should be ``context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)``

Comment: @AnkitTiwari i did all the changes and still having : 'super' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: from which file and from which line it's coming did you called ``super().get()`` somewhere in your file ?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari yes , but in another view

Comment: Does error show that view name for that file name ?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari no, i updated the traceback in the question

Comment: can you provide your **urls.py**

Comment: @AnkitTiwari i've put ir in the question

Comment: check some where you're trying to access invalid view in your ``urls.py`` check all ``urls.py`` for invalid view